# python __init_subclass__ with multiple classes. why doesn't __init_subclass get called twice?

Tags: python

I was searching for information on using __init_subclass__ with multiple classes and I came across this bug report: https://bugs.python.org/issue42674

the submitter stated that __init_subclass__ was only called once instead of twice

the issued was closed as not a bug, with this comment:

> The two subclasses in the test script are not calling super().  When they do, both **init_subclasses** are called.

The report came with the following code:

```
class ClassOne:
    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        print(f"ClassOne.__init_subclass__( cls = {cls} )")

class ClassTwo:
    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        print(f"ClassTwo.__init_subclass__( cls = {cls} )")


class MyClass(ClassOne, ClassTwo):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        super(ClassOne, self).__init__()
```

I can't figure out how to trigger both __init_subclass__ methods. Here's my attempt:

```
class ClassOne:
    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        print(f"ClassOne.__init_subclass__( cls = {cls} )")

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(f"ClassOne.__init__( self = {self} )")

class ClassTwo:
    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        print(f"ClassTwo.__init_subclass__( cls = {cls} )")

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(f"ClassTwo.__init__( self = {self} )")

class MyClass(ClassOne, ClassTwo):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClassOne, self).__init__()
        super(ClassTwo, self).__init__()
```

and the results:

```
> python3 init_subclass.py
ClassOne.__init_subclass__( cls = <class '__main__.MyClass'> )
```

I'm running python 3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a class is created by the metaclass `type`, the `__init_subclass__` class method is called on its `super()` object, as can been seen in its Python-equivalent [implementation details](https://peps.python.org/pep-0487/#implementation-details):

```
class NewType(type):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) != 3:
            return super().__new__(cls, *args)
        name, bases, ns = args
        init = ns.get('__init_subclass__')
        if isinstance(init, types.FunctionType):
            ns['__init_subclass__'] = classmethod(init)
        self = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, ns)
        for k, v in self.__dict__.items():
            func = getattr(v, '__set_name__', None)
            if func is not None:
                func(self, k)
        super(self, self).__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        return self
```

So the attribute name `__init_subclass__` follows the usual [MRO](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#custom-classes) rule of resolving in the base class that first defines this attribute. In the test case of the bug report, that's `ClassOne`, and since `ClassOne.__init_subclass__` doesn't call `super().__init_subclass__`, the baton never gets passed to `ClassTwo`, the next base class in the MRO, resulting in only an output from `ClassOne.__init_subclass__`.

This can be remedied by making each `__init_subclass__` method cooperative with a call to `super().__init_subclass__` so that the `__init_subclass__` method of all base classes are called:

```
class ClassOne:
    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        super().__init_subclass__()
        print(f"ClassOne.__init_subclass__( cls = {cls} )")

class ClassTwo:
    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        super().__init_subclass__()
        print(f"ClassTwo.__init_subclass__( cls = {cls} )")
```

Answer (score 2):

The response actually meant that `super().__init_subclass__` need to be called in each of the `__init_subclass__` classmethods, as per this section in [PEP-0487](https://peps.python.org/pep-0487/#new-ways-of-using-classes):

```py
class ClassOne:
    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        print(f"ClassOne.__init_subclass__( cls = {cls} )")

class ClassTwo:
    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        print(f"ClassTwo.__init_subclass__( cls = {cls} )")


class MyClass(ClassOne, ClassTwo):
    ...
```

Which should now result in both `__init_subclass__` being called:

```
ClassTwo.__init_subclass__( cls = <class '__main__.MyClass'> )
ClassOne.__init_subclass__( cls = <class '__main__.MyClass'> )
```

Comment: Would it maybe make more sense or this demonstration to call `super().__init__subclass__(**kwargs)` after the print statement, to make it clearer what the MRO Order was?

Comment: The other answer goes much deeper into the MRO.